# How to get BTC-AUD buy price without fees

Tags: api, fee

Is there any way to get the exchange rates without fees factored in because they seem to vary based on transaction volume and payment method?

The API documentation says:

> Note that exchange rates fluctuates so the price is only correct for
>   seconds at the time. This buy price includes standard Coinbase fee
>   (1%) but excludes any other fees including bank fees.

Source: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-exchange-rates

So the assumption is you can divide the exchange rate returned by 1.01 to get the fee excluding the standard Coinbase fee of 1% and conversely for sell price, you would multiply by 1.01.

However, the pricing from November 2017 has a much more complex pricing structure and makes no reference to the "standard Coinbase fee" referred to in the documentation.

See https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2109597-coinbase-pricing-fees-disclosures